# Send batch of posts as HTML Email?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, email, html-email

Looking for a little help getting to grips with a quote, part of which is producing quarterly reports consisting on all the posts from that quarter.

My question is two fold - Is there a plugin that can do this sort of thing? Or of not, any clue as to where to start coding it?

Cheers

Comment: Have you checked out: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress3-invoice/ ?

Comment: not really what I am looking for. I need a plugin what can send out digests of posts from a specific time period.

Comment: Apologies, read the question a little too fast. I can't follow what you're asking though, are these reports that you intend to email to users or something you want to store in the DB? Any chance you can give some more context to how this functionality should work and precisely what it should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a mailing plugin that can send mails in digests. One example is [Subscribe2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe2/), which can be set from once hourly to weekly, but you can probably modify the code so it extends to quarterly mailings.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually gone a completely different route. I'm using the [Mailchimp](http://eepurl.com/cGE-w) automatic RSS reader to send out Newsletters from WordPress Posts. Basically what you want to do is create a custom RSS feed (very easy), Yoast has an [excellent article](http://yoast.com/custom-rss-feeds-wordpress/), and then feed that to Mailchimp. MC will automatically find out which posts are new and send them out to whoever requires them on a weekly/monthly basis. Hope that helps.

Comment: does it do quarterly?

Comment: Don't think so, but I wouldn't exclude it as an option for the future.