# Automatically email daily archive

Tags: email, automation, newsletter

Is it possible to automatically email the daily archive.php page as an html email newsletter?

For example, at 4am every weekday WordPress would send an email of the 2011/04/25/ page.

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are plugins or other external solutions to do this, [this related question lists some of them](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9506/send-batch-of-posts-as-html-email).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think this is built into WordPress currently. This would probably need to be custom-built. It would be some php code that is attached to a cron job. Set the cron job to run every day, and have your php script email out the page.

These resources may help:
http://ss64.com/osx/crontab.html (via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256429/how-to-use-crontab-for-sending-weekly-email-in-php)

Comment: Just to let you know that WP has its own cron system too